# IIS 7 "Send errors to browser" set to FALSE, but detailed errors still being shown in browser (Classic ASP)

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, http-error

I found a bug in IIS7 and am looking for a workaround. After turning off client side and server side debugging for clients that still have their Classic ASP sites on my server, I discovered to my horror, that IIS 7 is STILL sending fully detailed messages to the client!

I've specified custom error pages as well (all of which redirect to a generic error page except 404 errors - those just get displayed in full, including the internal path of the websites in question). I can't seem to find a work around or patch or anything.

I did a hack that generates "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." instead of displaying the 404 error by putting the following into the web.config file of the Classic ASP site in question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <remove value="index.php" />
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="~\error404.htm" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, the `httpErrors` tag doesn't seem to work properly for classic ASP sites, no matter what you put in the path variable, an internal server error will occur. The point is to remove the status code here as there is no way to do this globally in IIS 7 (at least that I can find). The good news is that there is no detailed 404 error, the bad news is that trapping 404 errors is not possible (for ASP).

Any better (working) ideas?

Comment: Detailed Errors will not be a `404 Not Found` check what the `500.100 Internal Server Error` is mapped to.

Comment: I've checked the IIS log and the application log and there are no errors reported. The IIS log only shows the page that was requested, but nothing else.

Comment: You said that *"that IIS 7 is STILL sending fully detailed messages to the client!"* so check `500.100` in IIS 7 at the `Error Pages` section for the website, where is `500.100` mapped to?

Comment: The 500.100 error must be from putting the httpErrors tag in the web.config file. I have no idea why there is a 500 error - but it's clearly due to the setting in the web.config (no errors in the IIS log or application log - total mystery as to what it could be, but it's the only way to keep the 404's from showing in the browser for now)

Comment: I found an error of sorts when attempting to access the site's Error Pages:  This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

this is a start

Answer (score 0):

On IIS, go to your Website, go to ASP and change the Debugging Properties like following:

[image]

Change all to "False" and done.

Comment: First thing I did - the problem is only the 404 Error still shows up - I think there may be another setting elsewhere. All the other errors are fine.